# Spark Scala read text file into DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I wish to read a file and store it into a DataFrame.
I am reading a text file a storing into an RDD[Array[String]].

```
val file = sc.textFile("/mockSmall.txt").map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
case class record(eventName: String, date: String, counter: String)
val solrDF: DataFrame = file.map{case Array(s0, s1, s2) => record(s0, s1, s2)}.toDF()
```

However, I get the following compilation issue:

value DF is not a member of RDD[record]

How can I solve this?
Note: I am using spark 1.6, thus I do not have sparkSession.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 2.0 Scala - RDD.toDF()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968351/spark-2-0-scala-rdd-todf)

Comment: @Rumoku No, it is not. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: you've missed: `import sqlContext.implicits._` read carefully related topic. It works for 1.6 too. Or check documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import `spark.implicits._` and everything gonna be alright

Edit :

for 1.6.1 users please import `sqlContext.implicits._`

Or :

use `sqlContext.createDataFrame instead`

Please refere the the official [SQL and DataFrames guidline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html) for more information